# Why does my <tfoot> border color not override my <tbody> border color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

```
<table id="tab">
    <thead><tr><td>hhh</td><td>hhh</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr></tbody>
    <tfoot class="foot"><tr class="foot"><td class="foot">fff</td><td>fff</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>

#tab tr td {
    border: solid 2px green;
}

.foot {
    border: solid 2px red !important;
}
```

Why does my `<tfoot>` border color not override the `<tbody>` border color? I would also like to make the border-top color in `<tfoot>` red.

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/S8tUW/1/

Comment: You need to read about CSS specificity. The first rule is more specific than the second and thus overrides the second rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah yes. The rules for working out which border styles apply when borders collapse are a bit complicated. [*CSS: The Definitive Guide* by Eric Meyer](http://www.amazon.co.uk/CSS-Definitive-Guide-Eric-Meyer/dp/0596527330) has the best explanation I know of.

In order to make the top borders of the cells in your `<tfoot>` red, you actually need to remove the bottom border styles for the table cells in your `<tbody>`:

```
#tab tr td {
    border: solid 2px green;
}

#tab tfoot tr td {
    border-color: red;
}

#tab tbody tr td {
    border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

(See http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/S8tUW/28/)

Answer (score 6):

write like this :

```
.foot tr td{
    border: solid 2px red !important;
}

#tab tbody tr td{
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/S8tUW/19/

Comment: @PaulAttuck; check my fiddle example

Answer (score 2):

This is because of selector specificity.

The selector `#tab tr td` is way more specific than `.foot`.

Change your selector to `.foot tr td` and it should be as you desire.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/S8tUW/22/).

Comment: still is green instead of red

Comment: @Kyle: The top border of the footer cells is still green (in Chrome/Mac) no matter how specific you make the second selector.

Comment: Then you should make the bottom border of the cells above it red too.

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle defaults (annoyingly) to using normalize.css, which behaves counterintuitively - increasing selector specificity doesn't make a border "win".

I recommend using `border-collapse: separate;` (disabling "Normalized CSS" in jsFiddle), coding the CSS in such a way that the only adjacent borders are of the same style (i.e. "duplicates"), and then reverting to "border-collapse: collapse;` to get rid of those. (Which would be essentially Paul D. Waite's solution, that I'll have to apply to my work code now. The solution to this problem I came up with is http://jsfiddle.net/Eywjf/1/ which is excessively verbose and could be made shorter by collapsing.)

Answer (score 0):

The green border is applied to the cell, but the red border is applied to the section (`tfoot`). If you change the style from `.foot` to `.foot td`, it works better.